# Convert String into Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This is my String :

```
 "[[question1, answer1],[queston2,ans2]]"
```

How can I convert into Array like

```
[[question1, answer1],[queston2,ans2]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this easily by using `yaml`

```
require 'yaml'

str = "[[question1, answer1],[queston2,ans2]]"

# transform your string in a valid YAML-String
str.gsub!(/(\,)(\S)/, "\\1 \\2")

YAML::load(str)
# => [[question1, answer1],[queston2,ans2]]
```

or

```
YAML.load(str)
```

Comment: There is no need of doing gsub here, as you would get an array with string elements only. YAML.load(str) is enough here.

Answer (score 2):

With `str = "[[question1, answer1],[queston2,ans2]]"`, it not possible to get output like

`[[question1, answer1],[queston2,ans2]]`. We can get output with string elements like `[["question1", "answer1"], ["queston2", "ans2"]]` by doing just `require 'yaml'` and `YAML.load str`.

And if you have identifiers `question1, answer1, queston2 and ans2` then you can just get an array of corresponding values for these identifiers by using `eval str`.

Considering:--

```
question1 = "Which language is the best language?"
answer1 = "Ruby"
queston2 = "Which framework is the best framework?"
ans2 = "Rails 4.1"
```

We will get an array like following:--

```
eval str
=> [["Which language is the best language?", "Ruby"], 
     ["Which framework is the best framework?", "Rails 4.1"]]
```